# Index out of bounds error for DAG

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, directed-acyclic-graphs, longest-path

I'm writing a program to find the longest path for a DAG with input from standard in.I finally got it to compile, with it saying it is using unchecked or unsafe operations due to my Array list, but I am getting an index out of bounds error and it feels like I have tried changing every loop I must be missing something, thanks in advanced for any tips. 
Here is my code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class countLongPaths
{
static final int NINF = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
public class AdjListNode
{
    private int v;
    private int weight;
    AdjListNode(int inV, int inW) 
        { 
            v = inV;  
            weight = inW; 
        }
    int getV() 
        { 
            return v; 
        }
    int getWeight()  
        { 
            return weight; 
        }
}//end of adj list class

public class Graph
    {
        private int V;
        private LinkedList<AdjListNode>adj[];
        //set up graph with given number of verticies
        Graph(int v)
        {
            V=v;
            adj = new LinkedList[V];
            for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i)
                adj[i] = new LinkedList<AdjListNode>();
        }
        //function to add edges to graph
        void addEdge(int u, int v, int weight)
        {
            AdjListNode node = new AdjListNode(v,weight);
            adj[u].add(node);// Add v to u's list
        }

        //function to set order to go through vertices
        void setOrder(int v, Boolean visited[], Stack stack)
        {
            //Set node to visited when on it
            visited[v] = true;
            Integer i;

            //for all nodes connected to current repeat
            Iterator<AdjListNode> it = adj[v].iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                AdjListNode node =it.next();
                if (!visited[node.getV()])
                    setOrder(node.getV(), visited, stack);
            }
            //Once done with current add it to the stack
            stack.push(new Integer(v));
        }
        //function to find longest paths from s
        int longestPath()
        {
            Stack stack = new Stack();
            int LP[] = new int[V];
            //set all vertices to unvisited
            Boolean visited[] = new Boolean[V];
            for(int i = 1; i <= V; i++)
                visited[i] = false;
            //call set order function from each vertex
            for (int i = 1; i <= V; i++)
            {
                if(visited[i] == false)
                    setOrder(i, visited, stack);
            }
            //initialize distaces to all verices as negative infinity
            //set distace to source to 0
            LP[1] = 0;
            for(int i = 2; i <= V; i++)
                LP[i] = NINF;
            //go through vertices in order
            while(stack.empty() == false)
                {
                    int u = (int)stack.pop();
                    //update LP for adj vertices
                    Iterator<AdjListNode> it;
                    if (LP[u] != NINF)
                    {
                        it = adj[u].iterator();
                        while (it.hasNext())
                        {
                            AdjListNode i = it.next();
                            if(LP[i.getV()] < LP[u] + i.getWeight())
                                LP[i.getV()] = LP[u] + i.getWeight();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return LP[V];

        }
    }//end of graph class

    //Method to make a new graph
    public Graph newGraph(int number)
    {
        return new Graph(number);
    }

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    countLongPaths n = new countLongPaths();
    int GN = 0;
    int count = 1;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    GN = scan.nextInt();
    while (count<= GN)
    {
        int N = 0;// nodes
        int M = 0;//edges

        N = scan.nextInt();
        M = scan.nextInt();

        //setup a new graph
        Graph g = n.newGraph(N);
        //set edges for new graph
        for(int i = 1; i <= M; i ++)
        {
            int I = scan.nextInt();
            int J = scan.nextInt();
            int W = scan.nextInt();
            g.addEdge(I, J, W);
        }
        int dist = 0;
        dist = g.longestPath();
        System.out.println("graph number: " + count);
        System.out.println("longest path: " + dist);
        System.out.println("number of longest paths: ");
        System.out.println();
        count++;
    }//end of while

}//end main
}//end program
```

**EDIT 1**
with current code this is the error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at countLongPaths$Graph.<init>(countLongPaths.java:36)
at countLongPaths.newGraph(countLongPaths.java:108)
at countLongPaths.main(countLongPaths.java:127)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your stack trace says, the exception occurs in your `Graph` class constructor.

More specifically it happens inside the only line in your loop:

```
adj = new LinkedList[V];
for (int i = 0; i <= v; ++i)
    adj[i] = new LinkedList<AdjListNode>();
```

Assuming you've meant both lowercase `v` and uppercase `V` to be the same variable, you're defining an array of size `V` which is indexed from `0` to `V-1`, but you're running on it from `0` to `V` (your condition is `i <= V`), which is why you're getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Simply change the loop's condition (remove the `=`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i)
```

Comment: I think this helped but now im getting this:                                             `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at countLongPaths$Graph.longestPath(countLongPaths.java:71)
 at countLongPaths.main(countLongPaths.java:137)`

Comment: Yes, because all your loops exceed the limit. Just go over all of them and change the condition.

Comment: chaged them all sill getting this: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at countLongPaths$Graph.setOrder(countLongPaths.java:57)
 at countLongPaths$Graph.setOrder(countLongPaths.java:58)
 at countLongPaths$Graph.setOrder(countLongPaths.java:58)
 at countLongPaths$Graph.longestPath(countLongPaths.java:76)
 at countLongPaths.main(countLongPaths.java:137)`

Comment: You do `it.getNext()` which returns an `AdjListNode` object whose node value (`V`) exceeds the number of nodes, which is why you get the exception in  `if (!visited[node.getV()])`. Could you give me your input? Also, this would be much more productive and fruitful if you simply debug it yourself...

Comment: current input i'm using is this: 2
5 7
1 2 7
1 3 10
2 4 8
2 5 3
3 4 5
3 5 10
4 5 5
10 12
1 2 1
1 3 1
2 4 1
1
3 4 1
4 5 1
4 6 1
5 7 1
6 7 1
7 8 1
7 9 1
8 10 1
9 10 1

Comment: Okay, so that's your problem. You're given the edges as being between `1` and `N`, however, arrays are zero-indexed, i.e. go from `0` to `N-1`. Once you get the vertex `N-1`, you attempt to do `node.getV()` which returns `N`, however the array is at most `N-1`. Either go through all your code and change that, or simply in `addEdge` add `u -= 1; v-= 1;` at the beginning and adjust the vertices to be the indices.